# Disable KeyGuard in Android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, locking, programmatically-created, keyguard

I've had the same Question open for 9 months and haven't had any replies, so I'm hoping someone can help me this time. I want to write an intent that keeps my phone unlocked while connected to my home wifi. I've researched quite alot and kept finding the same answers.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
    KeyguardManager mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager)
    getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguard = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("LockOut"); 
    keyguard.disableKeyguard();
```

The problem is that this doesn't work with android 6.0, I've tested it with my old phone running on Lollipop and it works fine there. Does anyone know a workaround? Does it have something to do with the changement in the deviceManager class after API 23?

Comment: KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock
This class was deprecated in API level 13.
Use FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED instead; this allows you to seamlessly hide the keyguard as your application moves in and out of the foreground and does not require that any special permissions be requested. Handle returned by newKeyguardLock(String) that allows you to disable / reenable the keyguard.

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself. This only deactivates the keyguard for this specific application, my goal is to build a wifi smartlock, so that the phone is completely unlocked while connected to certain ssid's. Do you know of any way to do so? Thank you very much for replying and I appologise for the late response (Notification landed in Junkmail).